# Some system tray widgets randomly disappear for a while on Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde, widgets

Recently I have been using Kubuntu 18.04 which uses KDE Plasma 5.12.9.

I noticed that some widgets in the system tray (to be specific, *input method* and *ktorrent* widgets) disappear for a period of time (about more than 5 minutes) and then re-appear again. At the same time, a notification is displayed saying that the `connection to wifi network is active`.

I have searched for similar problems or issues but I haven't found a solution!